# How to get data from Api first and then call the my function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-grid

i have a function for grouping in kendo grid and i want Call it when the page loads

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getDeductionInfosList();

this.state=  this.createAppState({
        group: [{ field: "DeductionTypeTitle"   }], true)
  }
 
 getDeductionInfosList(data) {
    GetRestrictionListService.getDeductionInfos( data,this.successGetDeductionInfos);
  }
  successGetDeductionInfos = (response) => {
    if (response.Result) {
      this.setState({
        items: response.Result,
      });
    
    }
  };
createAppState(dataState, collapseAll) {
  const dataResult = process( this.state.items, dataState);
  console.log(this.state.items)
  if (collapseAll) {
    dataResult.data.forEach(dataItem => dataItem.expanded = false);

  }
  this.setState({
    dataResult: dataResult,
      dataState: dataState 
  }) ;


}
```

But when I use it in the  componentDidMount Returns the item empty array How to get data from Api first and then call the this.createAppState function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues in your code

1. setState may be asynchronous, meaning state wont get updated immediately after setState is call. It is mentioned clearly in React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous
2. You should never directly modify the state inside componentDidMount It is also mentioned here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly
   So I suggest modify the code as below

```
    componentDidMount() {
      this.getDeductionInfosList(data, function(response){
        this.createAppState({
            group: [{ field: "DeductionTypeTitle" }]}, response.Result, true)
      });
    }
    createAppState(dataState, items collapseAll) {
      const dataResult = process( items, dataState);
      if (collapseAll) {
        dataResult.data.forEach(dataItem => dataItem.expanded = false);
      }
      this.setState({
        dataResult: dataResult,
        dataState: dataState 
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the function to `async` and use `await` to the response.

`async function getDeductionInfosList(data){ await GetRestrictionListService.getDeductionInfos(data, this.successGetDeductionInfos);}`

Comment: I tried the way you said but still items into createAppState function is empty array

Comment: see the edited answer, I've been wrong on the first time. Not promising this time I'm right xD

Comment: You can also try to make the entire function async and await for the second one:
`async function componentDidMount(){....await getDeductionInfoList(data){...`. This is happening because the response come later than the execution of the function. So the execution must wait the response. Using await, you do this, it doesn't go farther until the response come.

Comment: Thaks for your answer